# ¿como puedo compartir datos entre 2 paginas?

Tags: html

**Tengo 2 paginas**
que estan construidas la primera esta hecha en(html,css y javascript) y la segunda esta construida(html,css,php) estoy aprendiendo recien todo este mundo de la informatica.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido. Te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que conozcas la comunidad y [cómo elaborar preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para evitar votos negativos o el cierre de la  misma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Primera forma:**

Lo que tendrias que utilizar seria crear apis en cada uno de tus paginas y que se conectemen mediante estas Apis que construyas.

Para crear una api en PHP [ver aqui](https://medium.com/@harshithdwivedi/creating-an-api-in-php-90e015e6c157)
Para consumir una api en PHP [ver aqui](https://medium.com/hackernoon/creating-rest-api-in-php-using-guzzle-d6a890499b02)
Para crear/consumir una api en javascript [ver aqui](https://medium.com/geekculture/creating-and-consuming-restful-apis-with-javascript-fcb761d4bf83)

Al final vas a crear la api de web A, mientras que la web B va a comsumir la data de la api A y viceversa.

**Segunda forma:**

Seria que utilices una base datos comun para para las 2 paginas asi se conecten a la misma base datos.
Pero lo optimo seria que pagina que tengas tenga su propia base datos.

Comment: Roly, tu respuesta, tal como está debería ir en la sección de comentarios. Te sugiero revisar [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para que conozcas como responder en la comunidad.

Comment: Explica un poco que necesita hacer con esos proyectos, que tipo de data se envía y de "donde hacia donde".
No se puede saber si queres "compartir" data del proyecto de `php ` al proyecto `html`

Comment: Aunque teoricamente este enlace conteste la pregunta, es preferible que incluyas las partes esenciales del mismo en la respuesta. Los enlaces pueden caducar y desaparecer. Ademas llevar al usuario a que lea en otro lugar la respuesta, no es la mejor opción.